# org/springframework/metadata/Attributes not found in spring3.0?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

may i know which jar is this class java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/metadata/Attributes located? i cannot find it inside org.springframework.aop-3.0.0.M1.jar  . but in older version of spring, it exist spring2.0   .

the reason i need this file is because i am trying out spring modules 0.9 @Cacheable tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metadata package does not exist in Spring 3.0. I suspect that Spring Modules is currently not compatible with 3.0, you need to use 2.5.x instead.

**edit**: The [Spring Modules](https://springmodules.dev.java.net/) project is dead. No indication of what, if anything, is replacing it.

Answer (score 1):

The Spring Modules is dead.

Long live the Spring modules:

http://github.com/astubbs/spring-modules

Alas, Spring3 integration is still an issue... :(